# Cannot get corresponding value from one select box

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am working on a registration page where a user when selects its designation, its corresponding reporting head gets selected in "reporting head" field dynamically. I have used Ajax for this but somehow the reporting head field remains empty. Can I get some insights over this?? It will be highly appreciated.

Here goes my registration fields,

```
     <select name="designation" class="form-control" required="" id="desig" >   
             <option selected="selected" >Select your option</option> 
           <?php 
                $sql = mysql_query("SELECT id, designation FROM tbl_designation where id in (1,2,3,4)");
                      while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){   
             echo "<option value=" . $row['id'] . ">" . $row['designation'] . "</option>";
    }
 ?></select>

 <select name="reporting_head" class="form-control"  required="" id="rephead">
          <option selected="selected">Select your option</option>
     </select>
```

Now JavaScript+AJAX that I am applying,

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
$("#desig").change(function()
{
var id=$(this).val();
var dataString = 'id='+ id;

$.ajax
({
type: "POST",
url: "ajax_rep.php",
data: dataString,
cache: false,
success: function(html)
{
$("#rephead").html(html);
}
});
});
});
```

And finally my ajax_rep.php

```
 <?php

require("includes/config.php"); 
require("classes/Database.class.php"); 

if($_POST['id'])
{
$id=$_POST['id'];
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT reporting_head_id, reporting_head FROM `tbl_designation` WHERE  id='$id'");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
$id=$row['reporting_head_id'];
$data=$row['reporting_head'];
echo '<option value="'.$id.'">'.$data.'</option>';
}
}
?>
```

This is the HTML I am getting on ajax success,

```
 <div class="row row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-right">
 <!--/.col-xs-12.col-sm-9-->
 <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 sidebar" id="sidebar">
    <div id="left_panel" class="clearfix left">
      <option value="6">Sales Head</option>
```

Comment: First, don't use `mysql_*` functions. Use `mysqli_*` functions. `i` for improved.

Comment: i dont know why you are passing all these div tag with the data, it seems your server side code is not proper. anyway i can provide you a temporary solution at this time , but you have to look on your server side code.in fact your server side code should return <option value="6">Sales Head</option> this only

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV Yes this is ambiguous. I will remove this so only going through this, but anyway I am getting the desired <option value="6">Sales Head</option> but how can I show it into the desired field.

Comment: if you are getting only the option details then   $("#rephead").append(html); code is enough to show it in your dropdown list.

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV Thanks a lot . It worked. Big thanks for your time and concern mate

Comment: happy to hear that its working

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV If its not a problem for you then can I take your insights on something else related to javascript  only? As I am really not getting this JS stuff and feels like to be in foreign land.

Comment: sure, you can post your questions here. we are here to help people...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this in you loop while

```
    $list = '<option selected="selected">Select your option</option>';


while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
$id=$row['reporting_head_id'];
$data=$row['reporting_head'];
$list .= '<option value="'.$id.'">'.$data.'</option>';
}
}

echo $list;
```

And in your ajax success function do this

```
success: function(html)
{
  $("#rephead").html("");
  $("#rephead").append(html);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the time but may I know the while loop you have given do I need to place this into ajax_rep.php or in my registration page only

Comment: Sorry, its not showing any change on this. Something else to be done?